# how to animate the display property in css or an alternative, without using javascript

Tags: html, css, image, css-animations

so i am making an advertisement, which has animations using css only(this is a requirement for the project). The problem is that I am not able to remove the elements from the screen because the display property is not animatable.  I want to remove the elements from the screen because there needs to be a complete scene change 2 times, hence there will be 3 scenes. Old elements need to go away and new elements need to be shown , in a fraction of a second.

I have reached the following state using no javascript but i dont know how to make the 2 images disappear and make space for the next elements of text divs.

https://jsfiddle.net/br93px4z/1/

changes are that javascript has been completely removed
and the following css has been edited :

```
@keyframes scale{
    0%{transform: scale(0.2);}
    99.9%{transform: scale(2.3);left:280px;top:40px;}
    100%{transform: scale(0.0000001);left: -4000px;top: -4000px;}
}


@keyframes topToBottom{
    0%{transform: translateY(-100px);}
    80%{transform: translateX(700px) translateY(100px) scale(2);left: -248px;
    top: -62px;}
    99%{transform: translateX(700px) translateY(100px) scale(2);left: -248px;
    top: -62px;}
    100%{transform: scale(0.0000001);left: -4000px;top: -4000px;}

}
```

here is what i want to achieve but it is achieved using javascript:
https://jsfiddle.net/t6ackzeb/4/

important javascript used(just for reading ):

`````````````````````````
logo.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", postAnimation1);

    logo.addEventListener("animationend", postAnimation1);


    function postAnimation1() {
        logo.style.display = "none";
        part1.style.backgroundColor = "#d6a333";
        part1.style.backgroundImage = "none";
        txtAdventure.style.display="block";
    }

    txtAdventure.addEventListener("animationend", postAnimation2);

    function postAnimation2() {
        img1.style.display = "none";
        img2.style.display = "none";
        txtAdventure.style.display="none";
        part1.style.backgroundImage="url('https://i.imgur.com/KsS80IE.png')"
        txt1.style.display = "block";
        txt2.style.display = "block";
        txt3.style.display = "block";
        endLogo.style.display = "block";

    }

````````````````````````

So is there an an alternative to achieving the same results as display:none; but without using javascript ?

thank you

Found the solution thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/9166287/adnan-toky :
here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mnpsavkq/16/
`````````````````````````

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hHYXdbP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code sample.

**CSS:**

```
.animatedDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    margin:5px;
 }

.d1 {
    animation:hide1 10s linear 10;
    background:red;
}

.d2 {
    animation:hide2 10s linear 10;
    background:green;
}

.d3 {
    animation:hide3 10s linear 10;
    background:blue;
}

@keyframes hide1{
    0% {
        opacity:1;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    33% {
        opacity:0;
        height: 100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    34% {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        height:0;
        width:0;
    }
}

@keyframes hide2{
    0% {
        opacity:1;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    33% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    66% {
        opacity:0;
        height: 100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    67% {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        height:0;
        width:0;
    }
}

@keyframes hide3{
    0% {
        opacity:1;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    66% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity:0;
        height: 100px;
        width:100px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="animatedDiv d1"></div>
<div class="animatedDiv d2"></div>
<div class="animatedDiv d3"></div>
```